# Why do I have to hit refresh to get js slider to render properly?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, zurb-foundation

**URL FOR SITE**
http://ew.cayennecreative.com

I've asked several questions regarding getting a Foundation Orbit slider working on an Ember app in the past couple days...I apologize for spamming anyone who is following Ember questions on here.

My issue has been getting Foundation to initialize when I visit the site. I added this to `application.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(document).foundation(); 
});
```

and the slider now loads properly on refresh. However, when you enter the root of the site and navigate through `{{linkTo}}` to the page with the slider, the images of the slider are stacked, like its not recognizing the js. But as soon as you hit refresh and reload that specific page -- `/about/philosophy` -- the slider runs.

I'm sure this has something to do with the initialization of Foundation but I'm not sure.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I've tried initializing in the component:

```
Ew.OrbitSliderComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  initOrbit: function() {
    $(document).foundation('orbit', {});
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

Initializing in the View:

```
Ew.ConditionsView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $('.hidden-content').hide();
    $('.toggle-bar').click(function (ev) {
      var t = ev.target

      $('#info' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle(500);

      return false;
    });
   this.$().foundation();
  }
});
```

I've tried initializing in the View and the component. And I've tried adding the Foundation js directory to the head of the app. Still nothing.

Tried `activate` to get the the functoin to fire every time the route changes. Nada.

```
Ew.ConditionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    initOrbit: function() {
      $(document).foundation('orbit', {});
  }.on('didInsertElement')
}
});
```

**RAILS**

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require_self
//= require ew
//= require foundation
Ew = Ember.Application.create();

//= require_tree .
```

application.html.erb

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/fem3tnu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<!-- Uncomment to make IE8 render like IE7 -->
<!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /> -->

<!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/foundation" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/custom.modernizr" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Tried with and without the "vendor/foundation" include_tag

Comment: You are misusing Ember big time. You should not be doing DOM manipulation via jQuery, as you doing inside your view. I suggest you to read all [Understanding Ember](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/) section carefully.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that. In the meantime do you have any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm not familiar with Rails, neither with Foundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a follow up from the comments on [this post](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/handlebar-helpers-vs-ember-components/2791/6) I've removed the first call to `$(document).fundation()` and let only the one in the component's `didInsertElement` hook, have a look at this working [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UQOJIZe/2/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what makes your jsbin different from my app. Does mine being a rails app make any difference to how the js is being initialized?

Comment: @reknirt, well it seams to depend how things are loaded, I guess since it's a rails app rails is responsible for serving the files (html, js, etc.). right?

Comment: Right. I've tried loading the files every which way. See update.

Comment: I stripped out the rails backend. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I figured it out. It was a foundation problem all along. Since my site is responsive I don't have a height set on the slider. But Foundation has a responsive option that calculates the width and height of the container on the fly and dynamically inserts this container into your source code. However, there's a bug that sets height to 0 when you first load the page. Not until you resize the browser does the height calculation fire. Apparently I'm not the first person to run into this. Thanks again though for all your help. You taught me a lot about components verses views.

Answer (score 3):

Not being familiar with Foundation, if I had to guess I'd say that it only acts on stuff already in the DOM. When you navigate to the page with `{{linkTo}}`, you're not reloading the whole page so your `ready` callback doesn't get called. If you have any views that depend on Foundation, you'll need to define `didInsertElement` for them and then have your library parse the view's element there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you mean by have my library parse the view's element?

Comment: I mean in `didInsertElement` to do something like: `this.$().foundation();`.

Answer (score 2):

I found that this is a limitation of orbit. You have to manually trigger the `resize` event on reinitialization. This code fixed it for me:

```
$(document).foundation('orbit', {})

setTimeout(function(){
   $(window).trigger('resize');        
}, 0);
```

The `setTimeout` was necessary to prevent scaling issues.